# Using dropdown button and Materialize

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, materialize

I'm making a website that uses Materialize.
I have the following code:

```
<ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#" data-activates="login"><%= t('layouts.navbar_off.login') %><i class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down right"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
```

And:

```
<ul id="login" class="dropdown-content">
<li><%= link_to t('layouts.navbar_off.like_school'), new_school_sessions_path %></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><%= link_to t('layouts.navbar_off.like_student'), new_student_sessions_path %></li>
```

But when I click in the button, just an # is added to url. I have to refresh the page and it works fine.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate the dropdown?  I know the docs say you only have to if you dynamically create them, but I had to anyways.  I chalked it up to some weirdness with Angular integration, although your experience with the refreshing seems familiar.  From the docs:

```
$('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
  inDuration: 300,
  outDuration: 225,
  constrain_width: false, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
  hover: true, // Activate on hover
  gutter: 0, // Spacing from edge
  belowOrigin: false // Displays dropdown below the button
}
);
```